# Create SQL Server database by C# with filestream enabled fails

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create a SQL Server database with the filestream options enabled.

```
    public void CreateDatabase()
    {
        if (!CheckDatabaseExists())
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("c:\\databackup"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\databackup");
            }

            var filePath = Path.Combine(jsonParser.FilestreamDataPath, "c:\\databackup\\backup");
            var primaryPath = Path.Combine(jsonParser.FilestreamDataPath, $"c:\\databackup\\backup.mdf");

            var createDataBase = $@" CREATE DATABASE backup ON PRIMARY
                                        (NAME = backup_Primary, FILENAME = '{primaryPath}'),
                                        FILEGROUP backup_FileStreamGroup
                                        CONTAINS FILESTREAM(NAME = backup_Filestream,
                                        FILENAME = '{filePath}')";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=false; User Id=backup; Password=backup; Server=190.168.20.84"))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createDataBase, connection))
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get this exception:

> Directory lookup for the file "C:\databackup\backup.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.). CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

But the same code was working fine for a while without any error. But suddenly I'm getting this error. The requirements for this code to works is that path `C:\databackup\` has to exist at the SQL Server side. At this point, I have no idea why it is failing.

Comment: so do you have that correct path on your server side and you do have the permission to do such operations?

Comment: I should have it as it is. But I will double check.

Comment: I think you do not have the same path as your sql server instance. here is the helpful link for you:https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/01/27/sql-server-error-fix-msg-5133-level-16-state-1-line-2-directory-lookup-for-the-file-failed-with-the-operating-system-error-2the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-part-2/

Comment: You're checking for existence of the directory on the client and then using it at the server. The initial check is useless right now, unless this code runs in the very same computer as the server.

Comment: I thought I was the only maintainer of the SQL server. So my assumption was the physical path for the file stream must exist. But somebody else removed the path by mistake. So the above is working fine again after creating the path again.